# WSO2 EI 6.3.0 Log Error while loading the registry resource

Tags: wso2

I have a proxy in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.3.0 with endpoint configured in conf registry. Sometimes I receive errors in this proxy with message in LOG:

```
[2018-09-12 09:33:22,542] [-1234] [] [SynapseWorker-11] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpointFactory} -  Invalid endpoint configuration.
[2018-09-12 09:33:22,542] [-1234] [] [SynapseWorker-11]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration} -  Error while loading the resource conf:services/corp/servicev1/endpoint/ERPEndpoint.xml from the remote registry. Previously cached value will be used. Check the registry accessibility.
[2018-09-12 09:33:22,545] [-1234] [] [SynapseWorker-11]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://...address ommited...]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

It seems to me it doesn't catch the endpoint of registry or cache.

PS: In my registry the address endpoint is with dns name and when this error occurs the address endpoint appears with IP address.

How to fix this?

Below the sequence and endpoint:

```
<sequence name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_MessageProcessorSequence" onError="PessoaService_GenericFaultHandlerSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="PROXY_NAME" scope="default" type="STRING" value="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_LocalProxy"/>
    <property name="SERVICE_VERSION" scope="default" type="STRING" value="1.0"/>
    <property expression="$header/wsa:MessageID" name="MessageIdConsumidor" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
    <property expression="$header/ns:ApplicationName" name="applicationName" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="https://ws.apache.org/axis2"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_MessageProcessorSequence" value="Started"/>
    </log>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="envelope"/>
        <target property="BODY_ORIGINAL" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
    <dblookup>
        <connection>
            <pool>
                <dsName>ESB</dsName>
            </pool>
        </connection>
        <statement>
            <sql>
                <![CDATA[select codigo_configuracao, cnpj_empresa from esb.codigo_configuracao  where aplicacao = ? and tipo_pessoa = 'fisica']]>
            </sql>
            <parameter expression="get-property('applicationName')" type="CHAR"/>
            <result column="codigo_configuracao" name="codigo_configuracao"/>
            <result column="cnpj_empresa" name="cnpj_empresa"/>
        </statement>
    </dblookup>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:codigo_configuracao" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1 [codigo_configuracao]"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:cnpj_empresa" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1 [cnpj_empresa]"/>
        <property expression="get-property('applicationName')" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1 [applicationName]"/>
    </log>
    <call-template target="PessoaService_LoginTemplate">
        <with-param name="username" value="username"/>
        <with-param name="password" value="pass"/>
        <with-param name="companyHandle" value="-1"/>
        <with-param name="branchHandle" value="-1"/>
    </call-template>
    <xslt key="conf:services/corp/pessoaservicev1/transformation/InserirPessoaFisicaNacionalRequest_IntegrarRequestTransformation.xslt">
        <property expression="$ctx:AuthenticationTokenId" name="AuthenticationTokenId"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:cnpj_empresa" name="cnpjEmpresa"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:codigo_configuracao" name="codigoConfiguracao"/>
    </xslt>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$body" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_MessageProcessorSequence [request ERP]"/>
    </log>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="body"/>
        <target property="RequestERP" type="property"/>
    </enrich>
    <header action="remove" name="Action" scope="default"/>
    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://.com.br/corporativo/PessoaService/Pessoa/Integrar"/>
    <property expression="get-property('registry', 'conf:services/corp/pessoaservicev1/parameters/endpointCallback.properties')" name="endpointCallback" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsa:Action>$1</wsa:Action>
                    <wsa:ReplyTo>
                        <wsa:Address>$2</wsa:Address>
                    </wsa:ReplyTo>
                    <wsa:MessageID>$3</wsa:MessageID>
                </soap:Header>
                <soap:Body>$4</soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg value="http://.com.br/corporativo/PessoaService/Pessoa/Integrar"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:endpointCallback"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/pes:Integrar" xmlns:pes="http://.com.br/corporativo/PessoaService"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint key="conf:services/corp/pessoaservicev1/endpoint/ERPEndpoint.xml"/>
    </call>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$body" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_MessageProcessorSequence [ERP Response]"/>
    </log>
    <filter xmlns:ns="http://.com.br/corporativo/PessoaService" xpath="$body//ns:CodigoRetorno = 'ProcessamentoOK'">
        <then>
            <call-template target="PessoaService_LogoutTemplate">
                <with-param name="AuthenticationTokenId" value="{$ctx:AuthenticationTokenId}"/>
            </call-template>
        </then>
        <else>
            <call-template target="PessoaService_LogoutTemplate">
                <with-param name="AuthenticationTokenId" value="{$ctx:AuthenticationTokenId}"/>
            </call-template>
            <property expression="get-property('ReplyTo')" name="uri.var.full" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="get-property('ReplyTo')" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1_MessageProcessorSequence [Processamento NOK - callback endpoint]"/>
            </log>
            <call>
                <endpoint key="conf:services/corp/pessoaservicev1/endpoint/CallbackDynamicEndpoint.xml"/>
            </call>
        </else>
    </filter>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <p:insert_smart_proxy_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <p:message_id>$1</p:message_id>
                <p:correlation_id>$2</p:correlation_id>
                <p:to_address/>
                <p:reply_address>$3</p:reply_address>
                <p:message>$4</p:message>
                <p:status>OK</p:status>
                <p:data_processamento>$5</p:data_processamento>
                <p:relates_to>$2</p:relates_to>
            </p:insert_smart_proxy_operation>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('MessageIdConsumidor')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('endpointCallback')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:RequestERP/*"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_DATE')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$body" name="PessoaService_inserirPessoaFisicaNacionalV1 [SmartProxy Request]"/>
    </log>
    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:insert_smart_proxy_operation"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint key="conf:services/corp/pessoaservicev1/endpoint/SmartProxyDSSEndpoint.xml"/>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Content of endpoint ERPEndpoint.xml in sequence above:

```
<endpoint name="BennerERPEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="http://host/App_Services/PESSOAS/Service.svc/ws">
        <enableAddressing/>
        <timeout>
            <duration>30000</duration>
            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
        </timeout>
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Can you share the endpoint and sequence

Comment: Hi! I add the sequence and endpoint. Thanks!